# As3, OOP strategy for custom class DrawVectorLineArt

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, subclass

I am doing some math projects that require a lot of vector line art--that is a line drawn between to points with a circle at the start point and an arrow at the end point.  A call to Math.atan2() keeps the arrow aligned. I call this class **DrawVectorLineArt()** and it creates instances of 2 other custom classes **DrawArrow()** and **DrawCircle()**.

So far so good--DrawVectorLineArt() draws just what I need.  Now I need to **animate** the vector art.
So in a function onEnterFrame I want to update the postion of arrow and circle, the objects created by DrawArrow() and DrawCircle(), respectively.  I also need to clear and redraw the line drawn between them.  At this point I am not sure how to proceed in an OOP framework.  Do I need to create methods of my custorm class DrawVectorLineArt() to update the position of arrow and circle and subsequently clear and redraw the connecting line?

Any advice or links appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Do I need to create methods of my custorm class DrawVectorLineArt() to update the position of arrow and circle and subsequently clear and redraw the connecting line?"

Yes.

The arrow and the circle are very members of DrawVectorLineArt, and going by its name and choice of members, so should the line (if it's implemented through actual data).  DrawVectorLineArt should contain and implement the whole animation between the circle, arrow, and line.  As such, if the animation's supposed to be able to change after creation, the same instance of DrawVectorLineArt should be able to take any two legitimate points supplied to it (or that it becomes aware of internally, depending on what you're doing), reposition the three components, and turn the arrow and line appropriately, within its own code.